# Confusing JavaScript statement: "var x = new this();"

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance

I thought I understood the concept of the JavaScript prototype object, as well as [[proto]] until I saw a few posts regarding class inheritance.

Firstly, "JavaScript OOP - the smart way" at http://amix.dk/blog/viewEntry/19038

See the implementation section:

```
var parent = new this('no_init');
```

And also "Simple JavaScript Inheritance" on John Resig's great blog.

```
var prototype = new this();
```

What does `new this();` actually mean?

This statement makes no sense to me because my understand has been that `this` points to an object and not a constructor function.  I've also tried testing statements in Firebug to figure this one out and all I receive is syntax errors.

My head has gone off into a complete spin.

Could someone please explain this in detail?

Comment: Just a note: don't confuse JavaScript object references with pointers.  `this` "refers to" an object, not "points to".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`AJS.Class` effectively* translates this:

```
var Person = new AJS.Class({
    init: function(name) {
        this.name = name;
        Person.count++;
    },
    getName: function() {
        return this.name;
    }
});
Person.count = 0;
```

into this:

```
var Person = function (name) {
    this.name = name;
    Person.count++;
};

Person.prototype = {
    getName: function() {
        return this.name;
    }
};

Person.extend = AJS.Class.prototype.extend;
Person.implement = AJS.Class.prototype.implement;

Person.count = 0;
```

Therefore, in this case, `this` in `AJS.Class.prototype.extend` refers to `Person`, because:

```
Person.extend(...);
// is the same as
Person.extend.call(Person, ...);
// is the same as
AJS.Class.prototype.extend.call(Person, ...);
```

* There are a lot of cases I don't go over; this rewrite is for simplicity in understanding the problem.

Comment: Your help throughout this question has been amazing strager.  Thanks a lot, I really appreciate it :).

Before I mark this as an answer- I'm hoping you can give a confirmation of my understanding. 

Essentially, <code>this<code> still "refers" to a Function object in extend() (e.g. function Person() as above).  It is NOT an non Function object.

Comment: @user419125, Hmm?  I'm not quite following what you're saying here.  A `Function` is an `Object`; it's a special type of `Object` (a "subclass", if you will, with some other special semantics).

Comment: Ask the opposite @AdamMikulasev, if `this` was not a function at the time `new this()` is executed it would throw an exception, ergo it has to be a function. The only mystery is how it comes to be initialised so. Here is one such example `function y(){};y.a=function(){return this instanceof Function;};y.a();` that illustrates the point made by @strager that a function (in this case `y`) is just another object that can have properties whose values can be functions (in this case `a`) that may be invoked (in which case `this` is an object that is a function, hence `new this()` would be valid).

Answer (score 8):

In a javascript `static` function, you can call `new this()` like so,

```
var Class = function(){}; // constructor
Class.foo = function(){return this;} // will return the Class function which is also an object
```

Therefore,

```
Class.foo = function(){ return new this();} // Will invoke the global Class func as a constructor
```

This way you get a static factory method. The moral of the story is, not to forget functions are just like any other objects when you are not calling them.

Answer (score 6):

What is confusing you, I think, is just where "this" is really coming from. So bear with me-- here is a very brief explanation that I hope will make it quite clear.

In JavaScript, what "this" refers to within a function is always determined at the time the function is called. When you do:

jimmy.nap();

The nap function (method) runs and receives jimmy as "this".

What objects have references to nap is irrelevant. For example:

```
var jimmy = {}, billy = {};
jimmy.nap = function(){ alert("zzz"); };
var jimmy_nap = jimmy.nap;
jimmy_nap(); // during this function's execution, this is *NOT* jimmy!
             // it is the global object ("window" in browsers), which is given as the 
             // context ("this") to all functions which are not given another context.
billy.sleep = jimmy.nap;
billy.sleep(); // during this function's excution, this is billy, *NOT* jimmy
jimmy.nap(); //okay, this time,  this is jimmy!
```

In other words, whenever you have:

```
var some_func = function(arg1, arg2){ /*....*/ };
// let's say obj and other_obj are some objects that came from somewhere or another
obj.some_meth = some_func;
other_obj.some_meth = some_func;
obj.some_meth(2, 3);
other_obj.some_meth(2, 3);
```

What it's getting "translated" into (not literally-- this is pedagogical, not about how javascript interpreters actually work at all) is something like:

```
var some_func = function(this, arg1, arg2){ /* ...*/ };
// let's say obj and other_obj are some objects that came from somewhere or another
obj.some_meth = some_func;
other_obj.some_meth = some_func;
obj.some_meth(obj, 2, 3);
other_obj.some_meth(other_obj, 2, 3);
```

So, notice how extend is used in the example on that page:

```
UniversityPerson = Person.extend({ /* ... */ });
```

Pop quiz: When extend runs, what does it think "this" refers to?
Answer: That's right. "Person".

So the puzzling code above really is the same as (in that particular case):

```
var prototype = new Person('no_init');
```

Not so mysterious anymore, eh? This is possible because unlike in some languages,
a JavaScript variable-- including "this"-- can hold any value, including a function such as Person.

(There is nothing that makes Person specifically a constructor. Any function can be invoked with the new keyword. If I recall the exact semantics, I think they are that when a function is called with the new keyword, it is automatically given an empty object ({}) as its context ("this") and when the function returns, the return value is that same object unless (maybe?) the function returns something else)

This is a cool question because it speaks to a pretty essential part of JavaScript's neatness or oddness (depending on how you see it).

Does that answer your question? I can clarify if necessary.

Comment: The constructor function is given an empty object with `prototype` members filled (in short).  Also, while your conclusion is correct (that `this` is bound to `Person`), how does `Person.extend` end up to be the value of `AJS.Class.prototype.extend`?  (I know the answer; I'm just saying you didn't mention it in your answer.)

Comment: This should be the chosen answer in my opinion. Makes so much sense.

Answer (score 3):

Imagine the following situation :

```
var inner = function () {
    var obj = new this;
    console.log(obj.myProperty);
};

var f1 = function () {
    this.myProperty = "my Property"
}

f1.f2 = inner;
f1.f2();
```

Here the calling object is itself a function, so **this** will return a function, and we can [instantiate it](http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/).

In order to use **this()**(not **this**) the outer function(the context) must itself return smth that can be instantiated(another function):

```
var inner = function () {
    var obj = new this();
    console.log(obj.myProperty);
};

var f1 = function () {
    var func = function () {};
    func.myProperty = 'my property';
    return func;
};

f1.f2 = inner;
f1.f2();
```

Answer (score 1):

A simpler code explaination:

```
class User {
  constructor() {
    this.name = '';
    this.age = '';
  }
  static getInfo() {
    let user = new this();
    console.log(user);
  } 
}

User.getInfo()
```

Output:

```
Object {
  age: "",
  name: ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

see this link http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html It will tell you about the this keyword, but I am not sure what this() is, may be its some kind of user defined function...... that you are not aware of...

Comment: `new this()` is just like `var MyClass = this; new MyClass()`.  There's nothing special about the `this()` in `new this()`.

Answer (score 0):

"this" means the context of the function currently running.

The code you are posting surely appears in a function that act as a method for an object.
So the object is the context of the function.

"new this()" will return a clone of the current object after running its constructor function with the passed arguments.

Answer (score -1):

this() refers to the the function that the code is in, but this() would have to be within that function. Calling new this(); within a function would create a never ending loop. Calling it outside of a function would be redundant because there is no function/class set as this().

Comment: The looping would be completely dependent on the context, `this` doesn't *necessarily* refer to the current function, it does refer to the current object's definition in this case because we're in the prototype of an object, but say in an event handler `this` doesn't refer to the current function at all.

Comment: Yes; `this` is bound by the call, and not when the function is created.  Otherwise, delegation through prototypes couldn't function properly!