# What is this() in javascript?

Tags: javascript, this

I understand the `this` keyword in javascript. I have used it like `this.method()` or `this.variable =`. But what is this(). See the below code:

```
  static fromTX(tx, index) {
    return new this().fromTX(tx, index);
  }
```

Please help me understand the use of this() in javascript and in the above code example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Confusing JavaScript statement: "var x = new this();"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473591/confusing-javascript-statement-var-x-new-this)

Answer (score 7):

Inside a static method, `this` will refer to the constructor, so `new this()` will invoke the constructor:

```js
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    console.log('making instance');
  }
  static makeFoo() {
    return new this();
  }
}

const f = Foo.makeFoo();
```

Of course, invoking `this` like that is only possible when `this` refers to a function, otherwise it'll throw an error. *Usually*, `this` will refer to an object, not a function.

Comment: Just for the sake of adding something, to understand why "this" refers to the constructor, consulting a compiler's compiled code (like tsc) may help a lot: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log('making%20instance')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20static%20makeFoo()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20this()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20f%20%3D%20Foo.makeFoo()%3B

Comment: @briosheje It doesn't have to be that complicated at all. When you call `Foo.makeFoo()`, `this` refers to `Foo`. Period. That simple. And since `new Foo` works, `new this` works the same.

Comment: @deceze Usually, as far as I can tell, in many other OOP languages (take C#, for instance), `this` in static methods does not exist. Seing how it gets transformed in vanilla JS, to me, makes it easier to understand why `this` actually exists, doesn't it?

Comment: @briosheje If you need to readjust yourself with regards to other languages… okay. But the rule in Javascript is pretty simple, and should be regarded on its own terms: if invoked via `a.b()`, `this` inside `b` is `a`. That goes for any sort of object. (And from here you can branch into explicit binding and what happens in case of just `c()` etc…)

Comment: @deceze Yeah, I should've mentioned that the above comment was more likely a reference for anyone who is used to other languages. I just felt it could've been useful since in many other languages the `static` keyword makes `this` unavailable and, in that example specifically, if you're not aware about how javascript works it just looks.. wrong. Anyway, it was just a comment to add something useful to those who are somehow wondering **why** this exists in such a context from a "technical" overview. Anyway, it's way easier to point to the main rule as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Let us take a 2-way approach to the problem:
**First**, `this` refers to the current instance within the class and is a keyword in numerous languages.
`this()` is a call to the constructor and this can contain various parameters as well.
**Second**, looking at the code snippet, it is a static method- precisely a static factory method. Look it up to understand why and where to use it and more details. 
The snippet provides an API to create the class object from params `tx, index`. You would want to do it to make it more readable for the client who calls this API. It is safe to assume that you might have different APIs too in this method solely for creating an object of the class. Further, in such cases, the constructors are marked private to gain more control over the object instantialtion.